# How can I programmatically “eject” a keychain on OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, keychain, eject, lsof

I'm using a script to eject a small USB key I use as a “identity” drive, which contains some secure information. Of note, it has an OS X “keychain” file on it, which contains some of my more secure and important passwords (those I'm willing to commit to a password-management program *at all*, but which are too important to leave sitting on my computers or have synced to Dropbox.)

That Keychain file is symlinked from Apple's `~/Library/Keychains/` folder to this key of mine, let's say, `/Volumes/Key/SECURE.keychain`. When I eject the disk, this symlink disappears, and the keychain obviously ceases to be accessible within Keychain Access:

[image: missing keychain icon]

This is all well-and-good … except I cannot *eject* this disk, without quitting half of the programs on my Mac. For no good reason that I can tell, any application that accesses *any* Keychain for *any* reason, opens (and retains-as-open) every single `.keychain` file the system knows about. For example, as soon as I plug the disk in, when nothing at all has requested access to this secondary, secure, keychain of mine:

```
> lsof '/Volumes/Key/SECURE.keychain'
COMMAND    PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Spotify   2801 elliottcable  txt    REG    1,8    89096  319 /Volumes/Key/SECURE.keychain
syncdefau 4267 elliottcable  txt    REG    1,8    89096  319 /Volumes/Key/SECURE.keychain
```

How can I safely eject this drive, without *killing* every process that has that file open? Can I somehow eject the *file* from the processes, remotely, or something of that nature?

(Related: Here's my current, unacceptable, approach: https://github.com/elliottcable/System/blob/2a5917e/Dotfiles/profile#L73-L94)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only unlocked keychains will prevent you from unmounting the volume they're stored on. If you lock the keychain, you'll be able to unmount without any problems.

To do this from a shell (script), use the command line tool `security`:

```
security lock-keychain /Volumes/Key/SECURE.keychain
```

This will lock the keychain and allow you to unmount the volume (as long as *Keychain Access* isn't running).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why those apps retain the keychain, but you should try to force the ejection of the USB key using:

```
diskutil unmountDisk force /Volumes/Key
```

Without any problem (as long as those application shouldn't use that file in any way).

---

P.S.: If you deserve from re-linking the keychain each time, you may want to add the path of the keychain to

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist
```